# Set error bars to standard deviation on a ggplot2 bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a two-factor bar graph using ggplot2, where I used mean_se to add error bars with the standard error. I would like to use standard deviation instead of standard error.

```
library(tidyverse)

#load diamonds dataset
diamonds <- diamonds

#two-factor dynamite plot
plt <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, fill = color)) +
geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", position = position_dodge(width = 
0. 9)) +
geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_se", position = 
position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
ylab("mean price") +
ggtitle("Two-Factor Dynamite plot")

plt
```

Is there a way to do this similar to using mean_se, but to generate error bars representing one standard deviation? mean_sdl doesn't seem to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mean_sdl` takes an argument `mult` which specifies the number of standard deviations - by default it is `mult = 2`. So you need to pass `mult = 1`:

```
plt <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, fill = color)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_sdl", 
                  fun.args = list(mult = 1),
                  position =  position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    ylab("mean price") +
    ggtitle("Two-Factor Dynamite plot")

plt
```